# MenuItem doesn't appear on actionbar

Tags: android, menu

I can not make the menu items appear on the actionbar. They appears on the menu only.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Favorites").setIcon(
            android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Favorites").setIcon(
            android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I find the answer. I didn't setShowAsAction..